# Apache Iceberg ListType(StructType) columns not working in Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I am trying to ADD a COLUMN to an existing Iceberg table using Spark SQL but I get an invalid SQL syntax when constructing the string SQL.

The function that creates the Iceberg column is the following:

```
  def sparkTypeToType[A <: DataType](sparkType: A): IcebergType = {
    import org.apache.iceberg.types.{Types, Type => IcebergType}
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

    sparkType match {
      .....
      case d @ ArrayType(StructType(fields), _) if fields.length > 1 =>
        Types.ListType.ofRequired(
          0,
          Types.StructType.of(
            fields.toSeq.zipWithIndex
              .map(f => Types.NestedField.required(f._2, f._1.name, Types.StringType.get()))
              .asJava))
```

And invoking the `toString` method on it:

```
  val alterTableSQL: String =
    s"""
       |ALTER TABLE $tableIdentifier
       |ADD COLUMN $c ${sparkTypeToType(newColumnType).toString} AFTER ${sourceColumns(columnPosition - 1)}
       |""".stripMargin
  df.sparkSession.sql(alterTableSQL)
```

returns the following invalid Spark SQL (which comes from [here](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/blob/b7fb00735d25e53ce36f07e5af116c8ccd368011/api/src/main/java/org/apache/iceberg/types/Types.java#L730) I figure):

```
list<0: element required struct<0: name: optional string, 1: surname: optional string, 2: age: required string>>
```

In order for it to run successfully, I have to manipulate the string into the following which is what [Iceberg's documentation](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-ddl/#alter-table--add-column) says:

```
array<struct<name: string, surname: string, age: string>>
```

I believe Spark's create() method uses a Hive serde internally to create the table and that's why it does not get this error:

```
spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], schema).writeTo(tableIdentifier).using("iceberg").create()
```

Versions: **Spark 3.3.1**, **Scala 2.12.15** & **Iceberg 1.10**